# Deployable MFE using nextjs and module federation

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, webpack-module-federation, webpack-production

does anyone has experience using **Nextjs** and **module federation** for creating the **MFE**s that can be deployable?

I can see there are some limitations and we'll lose **SSR** in that case like [deploying micro frontends with module federation and nextjs](https://cogent.co/blog/deploying-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-and-nextjs/) or we have to use [nextjs-mf](https://app.privjs.com/buy/packageDetail?pkg=@module-federation/nextjs-mf) which is not free.

Are there other ways to implement it in a way that we can deploy it to production without these limitations recently?